# After 18.04LTS > 20.04LTS update I have no internet connection except with the live session DVD (Ethernet)

Tags: 20.04

Software manager notified me Wednesday that the update to 20.04.1 was available. I ran the update and saw no issues during it. After the restart I had no internet connection. I'm connected via Ethernet. I installed a new Ethernet cable however still no internet. I booted into a live session (which I'm using now) and internet works perfectly. I've not had this problem with any of my other LTS upgrades and not being well versed on networking I really don't know what/where to check. I'm connected directly from the desktop to the DSL modem. The computer is a Dell Optiplex 780 with updated BIOS. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

All connectivity problems have been fixed. The last real issue I have is this warning from my syslog:

```
postfix/postdrop[429191]: warning: mail_queue_enter: create file maildrop/252039.429191: Read-only file system
```

This appears to be related to Netdata which up until my upgrade to 20.04 worked flawlessly. Besides being written to my syslog it's also written to the Netdata error log. Currently I can't load it up in my browser (Firefox).

As if by magic, just like with the network connectivity Netdata started working after restarting for what seems like the 100th time. So, as of this moment all issues I had with the upgrade are resolved to the best of my knowledge.

But so far I've found and corrected these from my 18.04LTS backup of 30 Sept:

```
1. Bind9 startup script in /etc/init.d missing.
2. All Spamassassin rules in /etc/spamassassin missing.
3. All Spamassassin rules in /var/lib/spamassassin/3.004004/updates_spamassassin_org missing
4. Updates_spamassassin_org.cf missing in /var/lib/spamassassin/3.004004/updates_spamassassin_org missing
```

Comment: I've added the output to my original post.

Comment: I've added quite a bit of info since last night.

Comment: It looks like your ping was successful for both Live and Desktop ("*5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss*"). That means both connect to the internet properly. It looks like your problem has changed from connectivity to e-mail. If that's true please edit your question to clean out the no-longer-necessary connectivity information and focus on your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. As you can see in my post currently all issues have been resolved.